# Como puedo hacer un ejecutable con Javafx?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, maven, ejecutar

**El problema en cuestión:**
Creo un  proyecto de JavaFx > le pongo cualquier nombre y claramente me pide añadir las librerías de javafx se los añado como external jar al proyecto y luego le pongo en VM argument lo de --module-path etc y todo funciona perfecto dentro de IDE pero cuando lo quiero exportar me crea el Jar en el escritorio lo ejecuto y no aparece nada, miro los procesos y tampoco está.
Entonces mi duda sería :

1. ¿Cómo puedo crear un ejecutable con JavaFx una vez terminado el
   proyecto?
2. ¿Sería mejor la importación por maven?

Comment: Cuando haces Build del proyecto se crea un `.jar` ejecutable, puede que ese archivo esté en otra parte, dependiendo de tu configuración. Por ejemplo, en la carpeta `target` del proyecto. Si lees atentamente los Logs que genera tu IDE cuando haces el Build deberías ver que te informa dónde se generó el archivo.

Comment: Cuando ejecuto el jar me sale esto en el cmd :Error: faltan los componentes de JavaFX runtime y son necesarios para ejecutar esta aplicación

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto la configuración que tengo actualmente en un proyecto con javafx corriendo en una raspi. El plugin está en el file pom.xml dentro de la etiqueta build. Modifica el valor de la etiqueta mainClass por la que corresponda en tu proyecto. Luego compilas y se te van a generar dos jars, el que se llama tu proyecto + "jar-with-dependencies" lo vas a poder ejecutar sin problemas desde la consola con java -jar nombredeljar.jar

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.3</version>
<configuration>
<mainClass>com.tech.desktop.ebeer.App</mainClass>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<!--  Build an executable JAR  -->
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<configuration>
<archive>
<manifest>
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
<mainClass>com.tech.desktop.ebeer.App</mainClass>
</manifest>
</archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<archive>
<manifest>
<mainClass>com.tech.desktop.ebeer.App</mainClass>
</manifest>
</archive>
<descriptorRefs>
<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>make-assembly</id>
<!--  this is used for inheritance merges  -->
<phase>package</phase>
<!--  bind to the packaging phase  -->
<goals>
<goal>single</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Las dependencias que tengo en el proyecto maven son:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
<version>11</version>
</dependency>
 <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml  -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
<version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

Javafx no está incluido en el openjdk y tienes que descargarlo a parte.

Estoy desde el celu ahora, espero te sirva! luego edito la pregunta para emprolijar el formato.

Slds!

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, te agradecería mucho si pudieras explicármelo paso a paso, Creo un proyecto en eclipse > maven > y en pom.xml > añado las dependencias pero lo del plugins no se como añadirlo y despues > mvn install pero no se como llegar a hacer  que funcione :(